# Google Ads API error accesing with service account

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Hi I'm trying to connect an python script with google ads api.

I have:
Ads Account manager with developer_token and the the account level is in "Test Account"
Google ads api -> enabled.

service account added to the api and with file service.json and email like service_acc@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

google-ads.yaml with

```
json_key_file_path: 'service.json'
impersonated_email: 'service_acc@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
use_proto_plus: True
developer_token: 'developer_token'
```

client_ads_id (supuse to be in ads.google.com in help -> customer Id) 10 digits without

I can access client api with
client = googleads.client.GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage() with no error.

Then I try to create a user list with

```
user_list_service_client = client.get_service("UserListService")
user_list_operation = client.get_type("UserListOperation")
user_list = user_list_operation.create
user_list.name = list_name
user_list.description = description
user_list.crm_based_user_list.upload_key_type = (
   client.enums.CustomerMatchUploadKeyTypeEnum.CONTACT_INFO
        )
user_list.membership_life_span = 365

response = user_list_service_client.mutate_user_lists(
            customer_id=customer_id, operations=[user_list_operation]
        )
```

In the last line I get an error:

```
errors {
  error_code {
    authentication_error: NOT_ADS_USER
  }
  message: "User in the cookie is not a valid Ads user."
}
```

and in the middle of the exception I got

```
status = StatusCode.UNAUTHENTICATED
```

I don't know how to link the client ads account with the api service account.

I've try to:

1. The service account is not linked to the ads client. (I've invited to service_acc@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com but... obviously it doesn't arrive and doesn't accept the invitation automatically)
2. In [this doc](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts#prerequisites) talk about impersonate, and don't know how to do it

> A Google Ads user with permissions on the Google Ads account you want
> to access. Google Ads does not support using service accounts without
> impersonation

Comment: I have the same problem, could you find the solution?

Comment: Nope, not all accounts has allowance to the API, I believe that you have to pass a acceptation process, so I desisted :(